# combine csv-files with windows-1252 encoding using powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, encoding, merge

I've got a lot of csv-files I wish to merge using PowerShell. Previously, I have used following command:

```
(gc *.csv  -encoding utf8) | out-file all-files.csv -encoding utf8
```

However, the files I want to merge this time have windows-1252/WinLatin1 encoding. I have tried to merge them by dropping the `-encoding utf8` or by changing it to `-encoding default`, but neither gives me the result I need, because it changes the non-ASCII characters to literal `?`. Any advice?

Comment: From Powershell 6.2 onwards you can use `-Encoding "windows-1252"` or just `-Encoding 1252`.

Comment: @PalleDue Both give me following error: `Get-Content : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'encoding'.
At line:1 char:12
+ (gc *.csv  -encoding 1252) | out-file all-tweets.csv -encoding 1252
+            ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand`

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: This approach is going to end up with extra header rows in the result file…